# Can I use an Array Iterator to do the same function as a for loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, addeventlistener, arrayiterator

I'm trying to understand if it is possible to use an array iterator (like .forEach()) to complete the same functionality as a for loop.

I am trying to understand javascript event listeners and have written some basic code to help me learn

I have multiple div's with a class name of 'button'.

I have the functionality I want to achieve working using a for loop but have not been able to work out how to do the same with an iterator.  IS it possible??

```
// Can I use an Array Iterator to do the same operation here
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  addEvent(button[i]);
}
```

See a [JSFiddle of all my code here](http://jsfiddle.net/peterjsmyth/xe9vt16g/1)

I have tried using the .forEach() iterator but couldn't work out how to grab the array index in the forEach() iterator as I need to define which button to run the addEvent function on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`button`, *in code you only posted a link to*, is an HTMLCollection, so there isn't much you can do with it "natively"

However, using [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) you can "convert" it to an array, and then use the [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method - so, your code would be

```
Array.from(button).forEach(function(btn) {
    addEvent(btn);
});
```

or, even better

```
Array.from(button).forEach(addEvent);
```

If you are dealing with Internet Exploder, you'll need the Polyfill for `Array.from`

If you need to deal with Internet Exploder prior to version 9, you'll need the Polyfill for `Array.prototype.forEach`

The MDN documentation I linked to has Polyfills for both

Comment: Thanks for the help Jaromanda X . 

My Bad, I read Array when the doco said Array-like. I didn't realise this was an HTML Collection.

>The getElementsByClassName method of Document interface returns an 
>**array-like** object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

Comment: yeah, that's a trap :p